# Binomial coefficient programm outputs wrong results, if inputs are large(C++)

Tags: c++

I have created a programm, that calculates binomial coefficient:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int factorial(int num){
    int res = 1;
    for(int i = 1;i <= num; ++i){
        res *= i;
    }
    return res;
}

int binom(int n,int k){
    int factorial(int num);
    int binom_coef;
    binom_coef = factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k));
    return binom_coef;
}

int main(){
    int n,k;
    int binom(int n,int k);
    try{
        cout << "Enter number n:";
        cin >> n;
        cout << "Enter number k:";
        cin >> k;
        if(n < k){
            throw -1;
        }
        cout << binom(n,k) << "\n";

    }catch(int x)
        cout << "n must be biggger than k";

}
```

For small inputs(up to 10) everything works perfectly fine. But if I enter big enough n and k(more than 10) the calculations are totally wrong and I cannot figure out why is that.

Can you help me?

Comment: `factorial(n)` would overflow even for the modestly large `n`. You'll need to find a way to calculate binomial coefficients without first computing huge numbers.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik do you have some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factorial is a function that grows really fast. It may be that for `n > 10` your factorials already overflow the `int` type.

In fact, `12!` = `479001600`

You’re applying the theoretical formula for the binomial coefficient, but if you try the operative definition you may have less problems:

```
10 : 2 = 10! / (2! * 8!) = (10 * 9) / (2 * 1)
```

So what you can do is: multiply all numbers in `[n, n - k)`, then divide them for all the numbers in `[k, 1)`.

```
int bin_coeff(int n, int k) {
   int res = 1, i = n;
   while (i > n - k)  res *= i--;
   while (i > 0)  res /= i--;
   return res;
}
```

As you can see, you’ll calculate `10 : 2` by simply doing `90 / 2`, which are not big numbers, and you’ll even get a better efficiency for your algorithm.

Comment: Even better, interleave multiplication and division: `8 / 1 * 9 / 2 * 10 / 3 ...` . This allows even larger numbers without overrunning.